# Update column values while processing the mysqldb with mongify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongify

I'm using mongify to migrate my mysqldb to mongodb. The problem I'm facing is as to how can I modify the values of a particular column in the before_save block?

Consider the following example:-
I have the following column in one of the tables which is in a string format:

```
"assets" : "{\"original\": [], \"thumbnail\": [], \"type\": []}"
```

Now I need to convert this into a json object before writing it to mongo inside a before_save block in Mongify. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the follow:

```
before_save do |row|
  values = eval(row.assets) # this would give you a ruby object
  row.merge(values)         # this would combine the hashes together
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Be careful with eval(), this could do bad things to your system depending on the data that's in your `row.assets` field.